# How is the wifi module connected to the CPU on RPI-3?

Tags: pi-3, wifi

How is the wifi module connected to the CPU on RPI-3?

Using SDIO, PCI-E, PCI, USB or something else?

Comment: shouldn't `hwinfo`, `lspci` or `lsusb` show that?

Comment: Maybe, do you know what they show? I don't have a RPI-3 available at the moment, my purchase depends on which bus the wifi module is connected on.

Comment: Without loading up a Pi3 I'm guessing SDIO/SPI for the wifi itself and UART *based on datasheets for other similar chipsets*. The documentation is likely vendor only so is difficult to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi 3 and the Raspberry Pi Zero W use the BCM43430 as combined Bluetooth and WiFi transciever. It is connected via SDIO (for WiFi) and UART (for Bluetooth).

Sources :

- http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=140444#p936754